# How to escape a period and then include a wildcard in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am looking for a specific pattern of code in a directory(i.e. `sc.xxx(xxx)`). Then I do a `grep -IR "sc\.*(*)"`. But it doesn't work well.

I have tried `grep -IR "sc\.` and it works well. (I randomly picked several lines from the terminal)

```
test_zeta.py:    assert_(np.isnan(sc.zetac(-np.inf)))
test_digamma.py:    dataset = np.vstack((x + 0j, sc.digamma(x))).T
test_digamma.py:    FuncData(sc.digamma, dataset, 0, 1, rtol=5e-14, nan_ok=True).check()
```

But when it comes to `grep -IR "sc\.*"`, the terminal begins to give me wired results.

```
test_digamma.py:    assert_equal(sc.digamma(pts), std)
test_digamma.py:    assert_(all(np.isnan(sc.digamma([-np.inf, -1]))))
test_orthogonal_eval.py:import scipy.special.orthogonal as orth
test_orthogonal_eval.py:from scipy.special._testutils import FuncData
test_cython_special.py:from scipy import special
```

which those scipy shouldn't appear according to my logic. What step did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your regular expression is giving you those other results is due to the fact that you just added a `*`.  What

```
grep -IR "sc\.*"
```

is actually matching is the literal `sc` follow by 0 or more literal `.`.

What you probably meant was:

```
grep -IR "sc\..*"
```

A good resource for understanding what your regular expression is doing is Regex101.  Here's yours: https://regex101.com/r/RSGR0A/1

Comment: Thank you so much. And how do I capture the first appear symbol after ```*```? I want to capture do ```grep -IR "sc\..*(*)"``` to capture ```sc.(xxx)``` but not ```(sc.(xxxxx)xx)```

Comment: @NewtonTang Could you give me an example from your examples above?  Not sure I follow.  Do you want what is between the parenthesis?  Or what is before?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I think I've figured it out. Thanks a lot.